# Huawei Push notifications- what is time delay for push notifications with different priority?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Check on the Time duration for High priority notification :- As in the details how long does it take for the push notification with the higher priority to reach the devices. and also about the Low and Medium priority to notification . Is there a time to time for these kind of notification. If yes what are the parameter which we can use

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed time of receiving message, it depends on your network connection generally it will take approximate in secs. But if you want to calculate exact time we have a method called getSentTime() in client side using this you can calculate how much time it will take to receive notification message but it will be varying device to device based on location and network.

Similarly you can calculate on app-server side also by sending uplink messages.

Please check below reference link which will guide you to calculate timestamp in client as well as server end:

1. Client Side: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/remotemessage-0000001050171874-V5

getSentTime()- Obtains the time when a message is sent from the server.

2. Server side: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-uplink-api-0000001050170915-V5

Request Header

X-HW-SIGNATURE - Message header signature, which is mandatory, indicating the signature information sent to your server that receives uplink messages.

X-HW-TIMESTAMP - Message header timestamp, which is mandatory, indicating the time when the Push Kit server receives uplink messages.